# Как правильно доделать код?

Tags: c, циклы, ввод

Я думаю суть задачи понятна, нужно чтобы в том случае когда `a<=0`, выходила надпись о повторном вводе. Как это правильно реализовать?

```
#include "stdio.h" 
#include "locale.h"
int main () 
{
float a;
setlocale (LC_ALL, "Rus");
printf ("Программа для конвертации см в м,км\n");
do {
printf ("Введите количество сантиметров:\n");
scanf("%f",&a);
} while (a<=0);
printf ("Метров=%f\n",a/100);
printf ("Километров=%f\n",a/100000);
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, [так](https://ideone.com/HvwaDr):

```
int main ()
{
    float a;
    printf ("Программа для конвертации см в м,км\n");
    do {
        printf ("Введите количество сантиметров:\n");
        scanf("%f",&a);
    } while (a<=0 && (printf("Ошибка, введите еще раз!\n")>0));
    printf ("Метров=%f\n",a/100);
    printf ("Километров=%f\n",a/100000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли!